# System doesn't recognise model of my SSD disk

Tags: kernel, gentoo, disk, ssd

I have [Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus NVMe M.2 500GB](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-970-evo-plus-nvme-m-2-500gb-mz-v7s500b-am/) mounted on the motherboard and it works fine, but when I open for example [gnome-disks](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-apps/gnome-disk-utility) or [parted](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-block/parted) to get more info about disk, system doesn't recognise model of the disk. SMART data & Self-Tests are also disabled.

This only happens on the M.2 disk. Normal SSD works fine.

[image]

Is there any kernel option or system configuration that can cause this?

I have `linux-4.19.44-gentoo` kernel.

Comment: From your screenshot (no model on the nvme drive) [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1724370) may be related

Comment: @bu5hman It is probably related. But on Debian I can see model of the disk however SMART is still disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that in the newer version of [gnome-disks](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/sys-apps/gnome-disk-utility) the model is already displayed correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SMART was originally an extension of ATA. It seems most tools now still only support (S)ATA because of that. [Comparison of S.M.A.R.T. tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_S.M.A.R.T._tools).

As for model detection, I'm guessing the problem comes from the same direction. Probably `lspci` still prints the correct device type. For instance on my system:

```
$ sudo lspci -kv
...
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951 (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0
        Memory at dfa10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
        Expansion ROM at dfa00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=9 Masked-
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
        Capabilities: [158] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [168] #19
        Capabilities: [188] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [190] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: nvme
```

Comment: Thank you for info. You are right. `lspci` recognizes device type correctly as well as `cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/device/model`

Answer (score 0):

As per [Samsung's Drive Support FAQ](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/support/faqs-02/):

1. BIOS may fail to support the SSD if it is outdated. Please update the BIOS to the latest version.
2. When there is a problem with the port, BIOS may fail to detect the SSD. Connect the SSD in a different M.2 slot if you have one, and try again.

Samsung also has a [Facebook page for their SSDs](https://www.facebook.com/SamsungSSD/), and you may get a quick response by posting there.

Comment: Bios recognizes model of SSD correctly. Problem must be somewhere in kernel modules or system side. Thank you for advice about Facebook, I can try ask there.